# Hide button event when other button is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want a event in jQuery or javascript or something in CSS that can hide a button ("A" button) when other button ("B" Button) (not in a form) is disabled and the oposite. Show the "A" button when the "B" button is enabled.

The "B" button has code in angular, but I have not access to `$scope`.

```
<div ng-if="something" class="steps-pager ng-scope">
    <!-- More stuff -->
    <a href="" ng-click="goTo()" class="next" title="next step" tabindex="0" ng-class="{hidden:disableButton}">next</a>
</div>
```

I'm working in a front side (with analytics testing software) and I don't know what are all elements that have to trigger that "B" button enabling or disabling state. It can be on click, also can be on validations and other stuff.

I tried to test it with on change events but they only works on input elements. I tried to get the $scope but it apears to be protected. I have no access to $Scope. With an interval could be work, but is to heavy for this website to have an interval in each stepps of a huge proccess.

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: I think your question needs clarification. you are talking about two buttons, but they are not in your code. Can you add more information?

Comment: Hi I update the post with that info. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-hide` and `ng-disabled` in AngularJs to achieve the above scenario.

You can always assign the `ng-disabled` value dynamically with your other form validation results by setting the scope object to true.

Below is the working DEMO

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.disableA = false;
      $scope.disableB = false;
      $scope.disable = function() {
       
        $scope.disableB = $scope.disableA ? false:true;
      };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <button ng-click="" ng-hide="disableB" ng-disabled="disableA">Button A</button>

    <button ng-click="" ng-hide="disableA" ng-disabled="disableB">Button B</button>

    <button ng-click="disable()" ng-hide="">Disable B</button>

  </div>
</body>
```